# Is it possible to create a C# DLL of C++/CLI code using .Net Core 3.1 on Linux

Tags: c++, .net-core, cross-platform, .net-core-3.1

This might be a very specific question. But it might be interesting for some other people, too.

The setting might be quite common: we develop an embedded device using C++ and Linux and have a build system for this. With our device we ship a C# desktop app using a DLL based plugin mechanism. The plugin contains the shared logic used both on the embedded device and the app. To keep processes easy it would be best to create the DLL on our Linux build system (hence I would like to use .Net Core and not "normal" .Net).

As far as my trial and error showed it's not possible - even with .Net Core 3.1. Can you confirm this? The software is for windows only (although it's compiled on Linux) - so theoretically it could possible since .Net Core supports CLI/C++ in Version 3.1 (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/).

What I tried:

1. I compiled pure C# code on Linux to an exe running successfully on windows using the console app `dotnet`
2. I successfully created a simple C++/CLI test app on Windows using sample code following this guide: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/an-update-on-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core/
3. Finally I took the (probably for too naive) approach to replace the test app's .vcxproj with the .csproj of step 1 (.csproj seems to detect files automatically). I got the following error message:

> quote CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/home/vagrant/Projects/cpp_dotnet_on_linux/cs_on_linux.csproj]

Is there something I can improve or is the task just impossible (adding the cpp-files manually to .csproj, ...)? I'm afraid it's just technically impossible because I guess .Net Core is missing a C++ compiler on Linux but I'm not sure.

Comment: Correct me where I'm wrong, I don't fully understand your setup: You ship a device *running Linux* and an *app for Windows* that allows users to interface with the device. There is a DLL that is used by this app that contains the logic & device communication. You want this DLL & app to be portable between Windows and Linux by relying on .NET Core. The code that communicates with the embedded device is written in native C++, built for Linux, but then you want to wrap it with C++/CLI to be used from .NET Core. Is that all correct?

Comment: In most points you're right. But the DLL with the C# Interface is for Windows only but I would like to build it on Linux. But the C++ Code which will be embedded in the DLL will be used on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: In that case you should use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) instead of C++/CLI to interface with your native C++ code. This does mean that you'll have to build a version of your C++ library for each platform (.so / .dll) and then it may be possible to P/Invoke either library from a single .NET Core "DLL". (.NET Core can still build "DLL"s on Linux that are only meant to be used with `dotnet`, but they're not true Windows DLLs)

Comment: That's a good idea. I already knew about P/Invoke - that was our plan b. But using .Net Core as a wrapper which can be cross  compiled on Linux for Windows is a good approach. Since g++ allows cross compile too we could do everything on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI is not support on Linux.

Some sources:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-future-of-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core-3/ :

> We don’t currently have plans for C++/CLI for targeting macOS or Linux. Additionally, compiling with “/clr:pure” and “/clr:safe” won’t be supported for .NET Core.

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/659#issuecomment-539742740

> C++/CLI on Linux will not be supported and would be very challenging. It would require Microsoft VC++ to support Linux or require Clang or GCC to support C++/CLI. Those are both huge projects with uncertain payoff. It is also unclear if Clang or GCC would ever allow us to upstream our changes. Maintaining an up-to-date fork of a fast moving compiler project forever is very expensive. We have no plans to take on either of those projects.